# Induced EMF in single stationary wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

Suppose we have a conducting stationary wire in a uniform magnetic field: $$\mathbf B(t) = kt \mathbf u_z$$ with $k>0$. Assume the wire is a segment that lies on the $xy$ plane and its length is arbitrary (I will assume it equal to $L$). We want to know the induced electromotive force ($\mathcal E$) on the wire.

I know from Maxwell equations that:
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E = - \frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}$$

Which implies that $\mathbf E$ has curl equal to $\mathbf A = -k\mathbf u_z$. Finding $\mathbf E$ is impossible (as far as I know) because the vector potential of $\mathbf A$ isn't unique.

I have no idea how to proceed and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have seen [this similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304665/emf-in-a-single-moving-wire-in-a-magnetic-field) but the wire I am considering is stationary. I have also seen [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130519/induced-emf-in-stationary-conductor-lying-in-varying-magnetic-field) but it doesn't explain how to find $\mathcal E$.

Comment: First you should guarantee that the magnetic field is divergenceless; then you should impose a gauge, the commonly used Coulomb's gauge gives a divergenless vector potential.

Comment: @nodarkside thank you for your hint! I have googled gauge fixing and gauge theory and I am sure that the course I am following doesn't require this level of physical theories (it's just an introductory course on electromagnetism for Applied Maths students). Do you think there might be another way to find $\mathcal E$ or is that the only convenient method?

Comment: you can use the InertialObserver answer. You have to integrate over the imaginary loop contour, not over the wire length.

Comment: @nodarkside what do you mean by imaginary loop contour? The question should be solvable even without complex analysis.

Comment: The problem is underspecified, there is no single answer, as Vincent Fraticelli have observed. The reason is the Faraday law only gives us curl of electric field, but in general curl of electric field does not determine electric field. Boundary conditions are necessary as well, only together they determine electric field. Without those conditions, electric field can be oriented along the wire or perpendicular to it, thus changing the emf substantially.

Comment: Thank you @JánLalinský ! What you said makes sense and honestly also cleared some doubts I had about Maxwell equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the problem is not ill posed ?

The electric field associated with the magnetic field depends on the details of the circuit that generates it. Is the magnetic field generated by a solenoid of circular section or square section ? .... Is it centered on the axis?

The details of the electric field have no importance for a closed circuit but for an open circuit they are important !

Imagine that the magnetic field is created by a solenoid of circular section centered on the axis. The cylindrical symmetry easily gives the electric field from the Maxwell faraday equation : $\overrightarrow{E}=-\frac{k}{2}r\overrightarrow{{{e}_{\theta }}}$

For this orthoradial electric field, the circulation of the field depends on the position of the segment in the plane Oxy. If the segment is radial, it is zero. If it is normal to the radius, it may be different from $0$ ...

So ill posed problem ?

Comment: I want the $\mathbf B$ field to be uniform everywhere, I may have not explained the situation well enough in the question, feel free to suggest edits. I think that a circular and square solenoid should behave in the same way as the radii go to infinity but I’m not sure about it, it would be of great help if you could read my answer (especially the “conclusion” section) and tell me if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is not well posed.

Comment: In the example  of the centered solenoid, with the electric field perfectly defined, the result is independant of the radius of the solenoid. So, if you want, you can take the limit of infinite radius and the result will not change. In consequence, I am not sure that the limiting process of an infinite circuit of any shape has sense ?. In your proof, the mutual inductance with an open circuit is problematic ?  (Sorry for my poor english !)

Comment: @VincentFraticelli thank you for the explanation, it makes sense now! I have been misled by InertialObserver and nodarkside into thinking that there was an easy solution but your counter-example showed me that there can be none (and additionally made me question some wrong assumptions I had on boundary conditions). I accepted your answer, it’s the only correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Given the homework-ish nature of this problem, I will only provide a useful hint. First off, since you already have a physical $B$-field there is no need to fix a gauge, since, like I said you already have the physical quantity.

Now, as you stated what you therefore know is that

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -k   \hat{z}$$

(If you assume that the B-field has always been on).

**Hint**: Multiply both sides by $d\mathbf{A}$ and integrate. This means that

$$\iint \nabla \times \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{A} = -k  \iint \hat{z} \cdot d\mathbf{A} $$

Now, choose $dA \hat{z}$, and use stokes theorem so that we may write

$$ \oint_{\partial A} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = -k  \iint_A \hat{z} \cdot d\mathbf{A} $$

where $A$ is an imaginary loop of area $A$ enclosing the wire whose orientation is defined by the normal vector $\hat{z}$. This is a simple circuital law, and I trust you can take it from here.

**Hint 2**: Since the wire length is arbitrary, take it to be very large. Recall, Faraday's law of induction

$$ \mathcal{E}= \oint_{\partial A} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}. $$

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I have even more questions now. How is $\oint_{\partial A} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$ linked to $\mathcal E = \int_0^L \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf l$? You integrate over the boundary of $A$ while I need the integral over a single segment enclosed in $A$. Should I take the limit as $A$ "shrinks" around the wire? Because that goes to $0$ and intuitively I would think that there is a $\mathcal E$ on the wire. Is my intuition wrong?

Comment: +1 for your answer @InertialObserver. It is true that you do not need to fix a gauge for this case.

Comment: @nodarkside do you have an answer to my comment above? I still can't see how $ \oint_{\partial A} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$ gives me $\int_{0}^L \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$, the wire is a segment, not a loop.

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to integrate over the length of the wire.. Look up "Faradian Loop"

Comment: I am trying to integrate over the length of the wire because that's what the problem asks. I don't have a loop here, just a straight metal bar of length $L$ so I don't understand what kind of surface $A$ you are talking about.

Comment: You can read Vincent’s answer and Ján’s comment to see that the problem can’t have a solution because the question lacks boundary conditions.